# Classic ASP count occurrences in array and output the results

Tags: arrays, forms, asp-classic

I have created a string and need to simplify it so I can pass the correct information in the array to the next page.  `date1` - `date3` are actual dates, but to make it simpler I just put in `date1`, etc.

```vb
string= " date1,date2,date1,date3,date1,date2"
Array = split(string,",")
```

I need the output/organization of:

```
3 date1
2 date2
1 date3
```

so I can pass the information

```
3,2015-09-09$2,2015-09-20$1,2015-09-25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a Dictionary and store each date string as a key. The *value* of the key can be the count (number of times the date occurs).

For example:

```vb
' Split dates into an array...
Dim a
a = Split("2015-09-09,2015-09-20,2015-09-09,2015-09-09,2015-09-20,2015-09-25", ",")

' Store each date into a dictionary and count the occurrences...
Dim d, dt
Set d = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each dt In a
    If d.Exists(dt) Then d(dt) = d(dt) + 1 Else d.Add dt, 1
Next

' Concatenate dictionary items...
Dim k, s
For Each k In d.Keys
    If Len(s) > 0 Then s = s & "$"
    s = s & d(k) & "," & k
Next

Response.Write s
```

Output:

```
3,2015-09-09$2,2015-09-20$1,2015-09-25
```

Comment: thanks so much. I had the right thinking, and close.  :)  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help. If you found the answer useful, please consider [upvoting and/or accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).